# SQLAlchemy: multi-branch polymorphism and relationships through association tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, polymorphic-associations

I have a use case where I want to apply a polymorphic association trait to a potentially unrelated collection of types.  What complicates this use case is that some of these types are already using shared table inheritance elsewhere in the application for another purpose.  Basically I have a type which has a "source" attribute, and I need that "source" attribute to map to any number of potential sources, some of which are already using polymorphism for other reasons, and some of which are not similar in form or function so inheritance doesn't make sense.  I want the association to be more like a trait, that anything tagged/mixed-in with this trait is a potential source for my object.

I have tried to boil this down with an example where I attempt to use the association proxy example in the SA docs to model the class definitions and declared attrs.  I am clearly missing something and could really use some help.  I would expect the last print statement to produce the Julius Lab instance.

Does anyone see the error in this setup?  Many thanks in advance.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr


class CustomBase:

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()


convention = {
    "ix": "ix_%(column_0_label)s",
    "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
    "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
    "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s",
}

metadata = MetaData(naming_convention=convention)
Base = declarative_base(cls=CustomBase, metadata=metadata)


class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__ = "animal"
    name = Column(String)
    discriminator = Column("type", String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "animal",
        "polymorphic_on": discriminator
    }


class Slobber(Base):

    consistency = Column(Integer)
    association = relationship("SlobberAssociation", backref="slobber")
    association_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("slobberassociation.id"))
    source = association_proxy("association", "source")


class SlobberAssociation(Base):
    """Polymorphic trait that determines the source of Slobber, 
       be it a Lab or Spaniel or Person"""

    discriminator = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": discriminator}

    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.discriminator = instance.__class__.__name__.lower()


class IsSlobberSource:
    @declared_attr
    def slobberassociation_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey("slobberassociation.id"))

    @declared_attr
    def slobberassociation(cls):
        name = cls.__name__
        discriminator = name.lower()

        assoc_cls = type(
            f"{name}Association",
            (SlobberAssociation,),
            dict(
                __tablename__=None,
                __mapper_args__={"polymorphic_identity": discriminator},
            ),
        )

        cls.slobbers = association_proxy(
            "slobberassociation",
            "slobbers",
            creator=lambda slobbers: assoc_cls(slobbers=slobbers),
        )
        return relationship(assoc_cls, backref=backref("source", uselist=False))


class Person(IsSlobberSource, Base):
    name = Column(String())


class Lab(IsSlobberSource, Animal):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "lab"}



class Spaniel(IsSlobberSource, Animal):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "spaniel"}


class Cat(Animal):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "cat"}


engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(engine)

julius = Lab(name='Julius')
poppy = Lab(name='Poppy')
lucas = Lab(name='Lucas')
wyatt = Spaniel(name='Wyatt')
holmes = Cat(name="Holmes")

session.add_all([julius, poppy, lucas, wyatt, holmes])
session.commit()

slobber_ball = Slobber(consistency=8)
slobber_ball.source = julius

session.add(slobber_ball)
session.commit()

s = session.query(Slobber).one()
print(s.source)
```

Answer (score 1):

So this seems to work, but the downside is that I cannot query source directly on the most generic "Slobber" type, the source attribute is only available on those derived classes `Lab.Slobber`, `Person.Slobber`, etc. generated by the `slobbers` declared attribute.  This approach does at least enforce foreign key relationships, which is why we end up with so many different association tables.  On the other hand I start to wonder if that is a worthwhile trade-off vs just handling this with a single association table with a descriminator column and have the application logic handle the necessary constraints.

Any comments/additional answers more than welcome!

This was helped along by referencing this SA example:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/generic_associations/table_per_related.html

```
class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__ = "animal"
    name = Column(String)
    discriminator = Column("type", String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "animal",
        "polymorphic_on": discriminator
    }


class Slobber(Base):
    consistency = Column(Integer)


class IsSlobberSource:
    slobber_assoc_tables = {}

    @declared_attr
    def slobbers(cls):
        tablename = cls.__tablename__
        table_key = f"{tablename}_slobbers"
        cls.Slobber = IsSlobberSource.slobber_assoc_tables.get(table_key, None)
        if cls.Slobber is None:
            cls.Slobber = type(
                f"{cls.__name__}Slobber",
                (Slobber, Base, ),
                dict(__tablename__=f"{tablename}_slobber",
                    source_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey(f"{tablename}.id")),
                    source=relationship(cls),
                    slobber_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey("slobber.id"), primary_key=True),
                ),
            )
            IsSlobberSource.slobber_assoc_tables[table_key] = cls.Slobber
        return relationship(cls.Slobber)

class Person(IsSlobberSource, Base):
    name = Column(String())


class Lab(IsSlobberSource, Animal):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "lab"}



class Spaniel(IsSlobberSource, Animal):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "spaniel"}


class Cat(Animal):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "cat"}
```